# testng selenium webdriver is not executing tests in order

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have 3 tests defined inside a class

```
@Test
public void test1(){
enter userID
}

@Test
public void test2(){
enter password
}

@Test
public void test3(){
click loginButton
}
```

But tests starts executing from test3 clicks loginButton first rather than in an order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TestNG the ordering of methods in the class file is unpredictable, so you need to either use dependencies[`dependsOnMethods` or `priority`] or include your methods explicitly in XML[`preserver-order=true in your testng.xml`].

```
@Test   //( priority = 1 )
public void test1(){
enter userID
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods="test1") //( priority = 2 )
public void test2(){
enter password
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods="test2") //( priority = 3 )
public void test3(){
click loginButton
}
```